# dp:url-open ro read non latin characters from the message on the queue

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, transformation, mq, ibm-datapower

Am trying to read a message from queue using dp:url open. But response is failing since the message contains non latin characters(chinese,korean etc).

dp:url-open target="{$url}

response="binaryNode"/>

"

Is there a way we can read message which accepts chinese character as well

Below is the example character on the message.

教会通りの近く

Thanks,

Comment: Please, add MQ error and URL that you use

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we use url-open for reading messages with Cyrillic characters.
Check encoding settings on CCSI tab of Queue Manager object, I think you should use 1208 for it.

Comment: No i dint help. It throws error dp:decode resulted in non-UTF8

Comment: Also you should use MQGMO_CONVERT option in url-open or activate 'Convert Input' option on CCSI tab.